# calculating button size using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I follow the example along the PHP and MySQL Web Development by Luke Welling and Laura Thomson.
in chapter 6 there a //calculate button size that has each()function that deprecated in 7.2. According to the Visual studio hint. I could use foreach loop instead instead of each().

```
public function DisplayMenu($buttons)
{
    echo "<table width=\"100%\" bgcolor=\"white\" 
      cellpadding=\"4\" cellspacing=\"4\">\n";
    echo "<tr>\n";

    //calculate button size
    $width = 100 / count($buttons);

    while (list($name, $url) = each($buttons)) {
        $this->DisplayButton(
            $width,
            $name,
            $url,
            !$this->IsURLCurrentPage($url)
        );
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";
}

public function IsURLCurrentPage($url)
{
    if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $url) == false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could use foreach loop instead instead of each().

Yes you can use `foreach` instead of `each()` as

```
foreach($buttons as $key => $value) {
        $this->DisplayButton(
            $width,
            $key,
            $value,
            !$this->IsURLCurrentPage($value)
        );
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the _while_ anymore

Comment: @Triby thanks a lot i just totally forgot about it.

Comment: Its ok @RudulphValNario and btw glad to help you:)